# How to convert FITS to JPG in Java?

Tags: java, jpeg, imagej, fits

I need to convert a fits file to jpg in java. I've tried with imageJ but I need a simple library without GUI. I'm developing a web page in java and I need to convert the file in background (headlessly).

Answer (score 2):

[Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7497651/alex) solved it by doing this:

```
public void fitsToJpg(String source, String destination, String image){
    try {
    ImagePlus imageP = openImage(source+image);
    final File out = new File(destination+"preview.jpg");
    BufferedImage imagen = imageP.getBufferedImage();
    ImageIO.write(imagen, "jpg", out);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Fits.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```